Server become unreachable after 12 hours up
I have two servers (pub, priv), both communicates via NAT gateway, but now I'm getting an issue with my private server, after around 12 hours running, it just became unreachable, I'm not expert on network in linux so, if someone could explain what is happening and what could be done I'll appreciate a lot.
My client-server config:
runcmd:
  - |
    cat <<EOF >> "/etc/systemd/resolved.conf"
    [Resolve]
    DNS=185.12.64.2 185.12.64.1
    EOF
  - | 
    cat <<'EOF' >> /etc/network/interfaces
    auto enp7s0
    iface enp7s0 inet dhcp
      post-up ip route add default via ${ip_gateway}
      dns-nameservers 185.12.64.2 185.12.64.1
    EOF

My NAT server:
runcmd:
  - |
    cat <<EOF >> "/etc/network/interfaces"
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '${ip_range}' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    EOF
  - sudo sed -i -e '/^\(#\|\)IPV6/s/^.*$/IPV6=\"no\"/g'  /etc/default/ufw
  - sudo sed -i -e '/^\(#\|\)DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY/s/^.*$/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY=\"ACCEPT\"/g'  /etc/default/ufw
  - sudo sed -i 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
  - sysctl -p
  - |
    cat > "/tmp/heredoc_nat" <<-EOC
    # NAT table rules
    # NAT
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

    # Port Forwardings
    -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport ${ssh_port} -j DNAT --to-destination ${ip_accessories}

    # Forward traffic through eth0 - Change to match you out-interface
    -A POSTROUTING -s ${ip_range} -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

    COMMIT
    EOC


I've finally fix the issue, this error happens because the private ip not been static, I've found this question when googling https://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1868693 and the same solution was applied to me.
Also I've followed the hetzner docs in order to setup the static ip on my private server https://docs.hetzner.com/cloud/networks/server-configuration/#manual-static-configuration
at the end of the day my configuration is like
 iface enp7s0 inet static
      address ${ip_private}
      mtu 1450
      post-up ip route add default via ${ip_gateway}

